# Build libs in subfolder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

i want to automatically build the referenced lib in a "lib" subfolder. I don't know how to handle that. I tried to include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

in the App.config and that doesn't helped. All referenced files will still build/copied in the main output folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it going to both places or only the main output folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probing path is only for the loading of assemblies at runtime, not for compilation. If you want a referenced library to be put in a `lib` subfolder of your output path, you will have to put it there manually (e.g. using a post-build event), and mark the referenced assembly as `Copy Local = false` in its properties to prevent it from being copied to the output directory.

Comment: @MikeH: Yes, forgot that. Updated answer.

Comment: is it possible to include the Project.exe.config into the .exe?

Comment: @zAfLu No. The way the config file is loaded is down to the framework, so you can't put it inside the exe without having to do your own code to load/parse it.